# Angularjs how to save data using two-way data binding

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have an input

```
<input type="text" name="name" ng-model='user.name' 
       placeholder="name" ng-required='true'>
```

and field

```
<span class="name">{{user.name}}</span>
```

I want to save `user.name` in `span`, then delete input value, type another `user.name` and save it to second `span`. So how to save unique name of each `span`, if when i clear input field, span value clears too?

Comment: Look into `ng-repeat`, I've updated my answer and I believe it does what you are asking.

Comment: Thank you so much, Gary!  It should work

Answer (score 1):

You would need some type of action to take place so the code would know that you are done writing the name so for example you can have a `button` or if it's being done in a `form` then on the `enter` key it would trigger the code below.

You will also need to use an `ng-repeat` to display all the names

**HTML**

```
<!-- Enter in name -->
<input type="text" name="name"  ng-model='user.name' placeholder="name" ng-required='true'>

<!-- Save name -->
<button ng-click="saveName()">Save Name</button>

<!-- Display names -->
<span ng-repeat="name in names">{{name}}</span>
```

**Angular**

```
$scope.names = [];

$scope.saveName = function() {
  $scope.names.push($scope.user.name);
  $scope.user.name = '';
};
```

`names` will contain all the names that were entered into the input. Then `ng-repeat` will display all the names in `<span>` tags.